# DDD problem with aggregate design (users, authentication)

Tags: domain-driven-design, authentication, aggregate

We're having a bounded context dealing with **payments**.

I'm trying to model case, where **Merchant** can create another **merchant** and inherit some of its properties in this case: **users** that are needed for authentication to another bounded context (payment processor) that acts as open host service with anti-corruption layer on our side.

```
class Merchant {

  public Merchant registerSubMerchant(name, ..);
  ...
}
```

The problem is, that **User** is also an aggregate as **Merchant** is. The process will create an instance of merchant, stores it, but I also need to load all users from parent merchant, and assign them to newly created merchant and also generate new user for authentication against our system:

```
users.filter(user -> user.realm() == PAYMENT_PROCESSOR)
     .forEach(user -> {
       user.assignTo(merchantId);
       userRepository.store(user);
});

User anotherUser = new UserForOurSystem(passwordGenerator).assignTo(merchantId);
userRepository.store(anotherUser);
```

Whole process should be (I suppose) in one transaction to be valid. Now here's the problem: I'm breaking the rule (and I guess also many other) that only 1 aggregate instance can be modified (or created?).

I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure if users should be wrapped inside the Merchant aggregate or should know about some users and their passwords etc.. How can I model such situation?

Comment: User shouldn't be an aggregate.  You're thinking at the wrong level of abstraction; a User is an Entity.  So is Merchant.

Comment: Look at [Fowler's description of DDD Aggregate:](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) *"A DDD aggregate is a **cluster of domain objects that can be treated as a single unit.**"*

Comment: So you're suggesting to model merchant as aggregate with list of users? Problem is, that relation between merchant and user is m-n and I'm not totally sure about loading and persisting such aggregate.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that an Aggregate is something larger, like a department or company function, not just a simple entity (which a `class` already more than adequately models).  You need to go back and re-read your Eric Evans book.

Comment: You must agree, that it's common, that aggregate is sometimes just entity (possibly with some value objects/another entities) that encapsulates/wraps some business behaviour. E.g. Product, or BacklogItem..Large clustered aggregates can lead to performance issues and to transaction inconsistency. Maybe you did come across this [article](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/). [Evans] is like Bible...can be interpreted in many ways.

Comment: You could have a 'saga' to handle creation of a sub-merchant. It creates the sub-merchant in one transaction, then adds it to each users of the original merchant (in separate transactions). If any fail, it handles the error appropriately (probably by retrying and/or notifying someone (user or administrator) of the issue - a rollback seems unlikely to be what you'd necessarily want here. You should only update 1 aggregate per transaction.